# Sort results in alphabetical order with type=text_en

Tags: sorting, solr

I have a solr text field as follows.

```
  <field name="news_headline_ln_en" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And when querying to sort results as follows, it doesn't show results in correct alphabetical order.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/news/select?fl=news_headline_ln_en&indent=on&q=*:*&rows=100&sort=news_headline_ln_en%20desc&start=0&wt=json
```

Result response:

```
    {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":45,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "fl":"news_headline_ln_en",
      "start":"11610",
      "sort":"news_headline_ln_en asc",
      "rows":"12021",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1478085256196"}},
  "response":{"numFound":12621,"start":11610,"docs":[
      {
        "news_headline_ln_en":"Eleven stocks up despite UAE markets decline"},
      {
        "news_headline_ln_en":"\nOil Prices Decline on Fed Rate Rise Jitters"},
      {
        "news_headline_ln_en":"Euro unemployment rate declines in February"},
      {
        "news_headline_ln_en":"Investors Holding’s Q4 profits decrease"},
      {
        "news_headline_ln_en":"DED honors ‘On Time’ in Oud Metha for excellence"},
      {
        "news_headline_ln_en":"\nTreasures From The Deep -- WSJ"},
      {
        "news_headline_ln_en":"Tunisia shares deepen early losses"},
      {
        "news_headline_ln_en":"EGX deepens losses in week"},
      {
```

As you can see it is not sorted alphabetically. Anyone does know a possible reason? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. `text_en` isn't suited for sorting, as it tokenizes the input and breaks the text up into separate tokens. These tokens are not usable for sorting.

The solution [is to add a `copyField` instruction](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields) that copies the content from the `text_en` field over to a field that *is* suitable for sorting, such as a `string` field or a text field with a KeywordTokenizer (which will allow you to lowercase the string, but keep it as a single token - if you want the sort to be case insensitive). If you're using a string field, you'll have to lowercase the field before indexing it yourself if you want the sort to be case insensitive.

```
<copyField source="news_headline_ln_en" dest="news_headline_ln_en_sort" />
```

.. and then use `sort=text_sort` for sorting. You can use the `maxChars` setting if you only need to copy the beginning of the original string (for example if you're sorting by the start of an article, you probably only need the first 20-40 characters of the article for the sort to be useful).

Also see [defining fields](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields) and the [Schema API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API).

Comment: I tried with your approach. But then it says `can not sort on multivalued field: news_headline_ln_en_sort"`  Here is the code that i used, 
`<fieldType name="news_headline_ln_en_sort" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>`

Comment: Set the field to not be multivalued: `multivalued="false"`.